# passing parameter to the powershell script file from C# environment

Tags: c#, powershell, parameters, remoting, powershell-remoting

i understand that the subject line looks too mundane and there are posts addressing many such questions. I did not find what i was exactly looking for and hence this post.

I am invoking a powershell file from machine A to be executed on a remote machine(machine B).

//here is the code snippet:

```
 Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
 runspace.Open();

Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
string scripttext = "$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString '222_bbbb' -AsPlainText –Force";
string scripttext1 = "$mycreds = New-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('TS-TEST-09\\Administrator',$secpasswd)";
string scripttext2  = "$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName TS-TEST-09 -Credential $mycreds";
**string scripttext5 = "Invoke-Command -Session $s -FilePath 'helper.ps1' | out-null";**

pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scripttext);
pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scripttext1);
pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scripttext2);
pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scripttext5);

Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
```

---

now in line
string scripttext5 = "Invoke-Command -Session $s -FilePath 'helper.ps1' | out-null";
i have to pass a few parameters(for example, username from c# environment : useralias) to this helper.ps1 file for processing. can any one guide me to a correct method of doing so?

TIA,
Manish

Comment: any final solution with full source code about it ?

Answer (score 0):

If the username and useralias come from the local machine then you can do so like this:

```
string scripttext5 = "Invoke-Command -Session $s -FilePath 'helper.ps1' -Args " + 
                      username + "," + useralias + " | Out-Null";
```

This assumes that your helper.ps1 file takes at least two parameters.  If so, then the values of the C# variables `username` and `useralias` will get assigned to the first two parameters.

Comment: Hi Keith ..your assumptions are valid for the case ..but when i try for these two variables, user name is supplied as 'username' itself rather than the value contained in this parameter. i tried even after removing " " from  -Args " + username + " but to no avail. can we rectify this behavior somehow?

Comment: That should work but if not, try this: `string scripttext5 = String.Format("Invoke-Command -Session $s -FilePath 'helper.ps1' -Args {0},{1} | Out-Null", username, useralias);`

Answer (score 0):

okay so here is the solution that worked for me.

it takes its bits from Keith's solution. the trick is to expose variables from c# using

```
runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("PSuseralias", this.useralias);
```

now using $PSuseralias as

```
string scripttext5 = "Invoke-Command -Session $s -FilePath 'helper.ps1' -Args  $PSuseralias;
```

this does the trick.